# Confusion about PMI payment on FHA

Tags: united-states, mortgage, first-time-home-buyer, home-ownership, pmi

I have been thinking to buy a house but I always thought that I would go for a conventional loan and put 20% down since my credit score is good and also I do not want to pay PMI for life.

Now, a couple of my friends bought theirs houses by putting only 3-4% down and went for FHA. When I asked them how do they feel about PMI, their response was that they only have to pay PMI for couple of months. This is very very confusing because I always thought that PMI is for life. If anyone could remove PMI penalty payments in matter of months then why wouldn't everyone go for buying a house?

So my question is:

1. Is it possible to have to pay PMI for only couple of months?
2. If so, how can I do that?
3. Also,if that is the case what is the reason for anyone to not prefer FHA over conventional?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I disagree with the other answers. Until proven otherwise, I believe you are correct and your friends are mistaken. (And the fact they claim the insurance is gone after just a few months strengthens my belief. Had they said it drops off at 20% equity I'd be more inclined to wonder...) AFAIK you cannot remove the mortgage insurance on a modern FHA loan, even once you have more than 20% equity. (Maybe the confusion arises from PMI vs FHA Insurance even though they are basically the same thing?)

From the [horse's mouth](https://portal.hud.gov/hudportal/HUD?src=/program_offices/housing/comp/premiums/prem2001):

> For mortgages with an FHA case number assignment date on or after June 3, 2013, the FHA insurance can be terminated by the servicer or holder **if the mortgage is paid in full before the maturity date**.

In other words, on new FHA loans, you have to pay off your mortgage (with cash or refi) to get rid of the insurance. But that statement seems obvious to me; can you imagine how awful it would be if you refinanced but still owed decades worth of insurance?!

Here's [another reference](http://themortgagereports.com/7570/fha-mip-cancel):

> The trick to getting rid of FHA mortgage insurance is to get rid of your FHA loan.

[Here's a reference](http://themortgagereports.com/14691/fha-mip-mortgage-insurance-premiums-mortgage-rates) which suggests the length of time you pay FHA insurance for is 11 years for loans with more than 10% equity, or the entire life of the loan for those with less. In the case of your friends with only 3-4% down, they would fall into the latter category of insurance "for life" (of the loan).

Answer (score 0):

PMI can be removed, with the bank's permission, when your equity becomes high enough to make it a confirming loan -- typically 20% or more of the value.

Comment: See https://portal.hud.gov/hudportal/HUD?src=/program_offices/housing/comp/premiums/prem2001 FHA loans may not allow cancellation of PMI until paid in full. In effect, it takes a refi to get rid of it.

Comment: That;s exactly what the confusion is. Most sources I refer to say that FHA PMI can not be removed. Then how come these people have their PMI removed?

Comment: @CoffeeBean PMI on conventional loans can be removed after you go over 20% of equity. Most loans will have a minimum time-span before they will re-assess the equity, typically in the span of a couple of years, not months. Not all sub-20%-down loans are FHA loans.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this answer is incorrect- OP is specifically asking about an FHA loan.

Answer (score 0):

You are sort of correct in your belief.  Using [this page as a reference](http://www.bankrate.com/finance/mortgages/7-crucial-facts-about-fha-loans-6.aspx) there are two portions of an FHA loan.  The upfront free 1.75% and the ongoing PMI.  The ongoing PMI can be removed from either an FHA or conventional loan.  But no matter what you will have to pay the 1.75% upfront fee of an FHA.

As such you may be better off attempting to qualify for a conventional loan considering that you have good credit.

While I do not have any experience with it, I imagine removing the PMI might be a bit of a pain.  Banks tend to resist the denial of income.

Comment: What makes you think that PMI can be removed from an FHA loan? The page you referenced doesn't seem to say that.